# Calculate the total by subtracting options - Dynamics forms - Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to calculate the total of the "score" fields of the nested form in the "qualification" entry field. Currently I can add the fields "score" and show the total in "qualification", but the problem is when I delete a field "score" I do not update the "qualification" field but it remains with the same result. additional can be put some restriction to avoid passing a grade, for example that this is not greater than 10, I would appreciate if you can help me.

Form_

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'dynamic-form',
    "enableAjaxValidation" => true,
]);
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->input('title', ['placeholder' => "Title Evaluation"]) ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_start')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'calendarWeeks' => true,
                        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => [0, 5],
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'todayBtn' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_end')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, "type_evaluation_id")->dropDownList(
                        ArrayHelper::map(EvalTipo::find()->all(), 'id', 'description'), [
                    'prompt' => '-- Select Type --'
                ]);
                ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'duration')->widget(TimePicker::className(), [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showSeconds' => true,
                        'showMeridian' => false,
                        'minuteStep' => 1,
                        'secondStep' => 5,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'qualification')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Qualification']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 9, 'placeholder' => 'Enter evaluation description']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="box box-success box-solid">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Questions Evaluation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 30, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelQuestion[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'item',
                    'puntuacion',
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th style="width: 500px;">Options</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 90px;">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="container-items">
                    <?php foreach ($modelQuestion as $indexQuestion => $modelQuestions): ?>
                        <tr class="item">
                            <td class="vcenter">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <td class="vcenter">1.</td>
                                    <td class="vcenter">
                                        <?php
                                        // necessary for update action.
                                        if (!$modelQuestions->isNewRecord) {
                                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]id");
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <?= $form->field ( $modelQuestion , "[{$indexQuestion}]question" )->dropDownList (
                                                ArrayHelper::map(QuestType::find()->all() , 'id' , 'description' ) , [
                                            'prompt' => '-- Select Question --'
                                        ] ); ?>
                                        <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]question")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title question']) ?>
                                       <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]score")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Score']) ?><?= $form->field($modelQuestions,"[{$indexQuestion}]justified ")->checkbox(array('label'=>'','labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),                    ))->label('You want a response justified ?');?>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=
                                $this->render('_form-opc', [
                                    'form' => $form,
                                    'indexEvaPr' => $indexQuestion,
                                    'modelsOpc'=>$modelsOpc[$indexQuestion],
                                ])
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px; verti">
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Crear' : '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>  Modificar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Js

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[id^="questions-"]', function() {
var sum = 0;
jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .remove-item").each(function(indexQuestion) {

    var amount = $('#questions-' + indexQuestion + '-score').val().replace(/,/g , "");

    sum += parseFloat(amount);
});
$('#question-qualification').val(sum);
```

});

Comment: [these](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/src/assets/yii2-dynamic-form.js#L26) are the events that are triggered via `yii2-dynamic-form.js` when you delete or insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a new [Javascript Events](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/README.md#usage) the **afterDelete** event and your JS wold be:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[id^="questions-"]', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .remove-item").each(function(indexQuestion) {
        var amount = $('#questions-' + indexQuestion + '-score').val().replace(/,/g, "");    
        sum += parseFloat(amount);
    });
    $('#question-qualification').val(sum);
});
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .remove-item").each(function(indexQuestion) {
        var amount = $('#questions-' + indexQuestion + '-score').val().replace(/,/g, "");
        sum += parseFloat(amount);
    });
    $('#question-qualification').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It was just what I was looking for.